# Firebase Function using Auth getUserByEmail

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a simple Firebase function using Firebase Auth that returns a user's uid if I send it a valid email address. No matter what I change I always get the same error:

*Error fetching user data: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received type function ([Function (anonymous)])*

To call it I use: ...cloudfunctions.net/checkemail?email=wyn@wyn.com
I have tried wyn%40wyn.com as well. The user does exist.

[image]

I'm obviously doing something wrong. But what?

```
   export const checkemail = functions
    .region("deleted")
    .https.onRequest(async (request, response) =>{
      const email = String(request.query.email);
      await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
          .then((userRecord)=> {
            const data = userRecord.toJSON;
            response.send(data);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            response.send("Error fetching user data: "+ error);
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

toJSON is a method. Therefore it needs brackets: `const data = userRecord.toJSON()`